# Express.js, Passport.js and SockJS: How to attach user socket to deserializeUser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, sockjs

In my new project I use Express 3, Passport.js and SockJS. I need to attach user socket to User instance for use it in route handlers. For example for notifications. Something like this:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
    req.user.conn.write('hello');
    next();
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using sockjs-node? if so, it should be trivial, however I would recommend not attaching directly to the user object, rather have some sort of socket service so that each user doesn't require a connection. otherwise you're likely to have a ton of open connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, because SockJS run on a separate server. All events should be handled within SockJS.